# Ffmpeg set output format C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I made a program that encodes a video and I want to specify the format as `h264` but I can't figure out how to do it. It automatically sets the format to `mpeg4` and I can't change it. I got my code from ffmpegs official examples [muxing.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c) and slightly edited it to fit my code (I haven't changed much especially did not touch the parts where it sets the format)

Here is my code so for (I have trimmed down the code slightly, removing redundant parts)

video_encoder.cpp:

```cpp
video_encoder::video_encoder(int w, int h, float fps, unsigned int duration) 
 :width(w), height(h), STREAM_FRAME_RATE(fps), STREAM_DURATION(duration)
{
    std::string as_str = "./output/video.mp4";

    char* filename = const_cast<char*>(as_str.c_str());
    enc_inf.video_st, enc_inf.audio_st = (struct OutputStream) { 0 };
    enc_inf.video_st.next_pts = 1; 
    enc_inf.audio_st.next_pts = 1;
    enc_inf.encode_audio, enc_inf.encode_video = 0;
    int ret;
    int i;

    /* allocate the output media context */
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&enc_inf.oc, NULL, NULL, filename);

    if (!enc_inf.oc) {
        std::cout << "FAILED" << std::endl;
        avformat_alloc_output_context2(&enc_inf.oc, NULL, "mpeg", filename);
    }

    enc_inf.fmt = enc_inf.oc->oformat;

    /* Add the audio and video streams using the default format codecs
     * and initialize the codecs. */
    if (enc_inf.fmt->video_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        add_stream(&enc_inf.video_st, enc_inf.oc, &video_codec, enc_inf.fmt->video_codec);
        enc_inf.have_video = 1;
        enc_inf.encode_video = 1;
    }
    if (enc_inf.fmt->audio_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        add_stream(&enc_inf.audio_st, enc_inf.oc, &audio_codec, enc_inf.fmt->audio_codec);
        enc_inf.have_audio = 1;
        enc_inf.encode_audio = 1;
    }

    /* Now that all the parameters are set, we can open the audio and
     * video codecs and allocate the necessary encode buffers. */
    if (enc_inf.have_video)
        open_video(enc_inf.oc, video_codec, &enc_inf.video_st, opt);

    if (enc_inf.have_audio)
        open_audio(enc_inf.oc, audio_codec, &enc_inf.audio_st, opt);
    av_dump_format(enc_inf.oc, 0, filename, 1);

    /* open the output file, if needed */
    if (!(enc_inf.fmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&enc_inf.oc->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            //VI_ERROR("Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename, ret);
            //return 1;
        }
    }

    /* Write the stream header, if any. */
    ret = avformat_write_header(enc_inf.oc, &opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        VI_ERROR("Error occurred when opening output file:");
        //return 1;
    }
    
    //return 0;
}


/* Add an output stream. */
void video_encoder::add_stream(OutputStream *ost, AVFormatContext *oc,
                       const AVCodec **codec,
                       enum AVCodecID codec_id)
{
    AVCodecContext *c;
    int i;

    /* find the encoder */
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
    
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
                avcodec_get_name(codec_id));
        exit(1);
    }

    ost->tmp_pkt = av_packet_alloc();

    if (!ost->tmp_pkt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate AVPacket\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    ost->st = avformat_new_stream(oc, NULL);
    if (!ost->st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->st->id = oc->nb_streams-1;
    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(*codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not alloc an encoding context\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ost->enc = c;


    switch ((*codec)->type) {
    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
        ...
        break;
    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
        c->codec_id = codec_id;

        c->bit_rate = 10000;
        /* Resolution must be a multiple of two. */
        c->width    = width;
        c->height   = height;
        /* timebase: This is the fundamental unit of time (in seconds) in terms
         * of which frame timestamps are represented. For fixed-fps content,
         * timebase should be 1/framerate and timestamp increments should be
         * identical to 1. */
        ost->st->time_base = (AVRational){ 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE }; // *frame_rate
        c->time_base       = ost->st->time_base;

        c->gop_size      = 7; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        //c->codec_id      = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
        c->pix_fmt       = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
        //if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO) 
        //    c->max_b_frames = 2;
        if (c->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
            /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
             * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
             * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
            c->mb_decision = 2;
        }

        if ((*codec)->pix_fmts){
            //c->pix_fmt = (*codec)->pix_fmts[0];
            std::cout << "NEW FORMAT : " << c->pix_fmt << std::endl;
        }

        break;
    }
     

    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    if (oc->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        c->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
}
```

video_encoder.h

```cpp
typedef struct OutputStream {
    AVStream *st;
    AVCodecContext *enc;

    /* pts of the next frame that will be generated */
    int64_t next_pts;
    int samples_count;

    AVFrame *frame;
    AVFrame *tmp_frame;

    AVPacket *tmp_pkt;

    float t, tincr, tincr2;

    struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;
    struct SwrContext *swr_ctx;
} OutputStream;

class video_encoder{
    private:
        typedef struct {
            OutputStream video_st, audio_st;
            const AVOutputFormat *fmt;
            AVFormatContext *oc;
            int have_video, have_audio, encode_video, encode_audio;
            std::string name;
        } encode_info;
    public:
        encode_info enc_inf;
        video_encoder(int w, int h, float fps, unsigned int duration);
        ~video_encoder();  
        ...
    private:
        ...
        void add_stream(OutputStream *ost, AVFormatContext *oc,
                       const AVCodec **codec,
                       enum AVCodecID codec_id);
```

I'm thinking that the example sets the codec at `avformat_alloc_output_context2(&enc_inf.oc, NULL, NULL, filename)` but I'm not quite sure how to set it to h264.

I've tried something like this `avformat_alloc_output_context2(&enc_inf.oc, enc_inf.fmt, "h264", filename)`

But it just gives a seg fault. What am I supposed to do?

Edit: I've tried adding these two lines to `video_encoder::video_encoder` by deleting `avformat_alloc_output_context2(&enc_inf.oc, NULL, NULL, filename);`:

```cpp
    video_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    enc_inf.video_st.enc = avcodec_alloc_context3(video_codec);
```

But it resulted in these errors:
It says this every frame (A bunch of times)

```
[mpeg @ 0x56057c465480] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=26822 size=31816
```

Says this once when the frame encoding loop is over:

```
[mpeg @ 0x5565ac4a04c0] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpeg @ 0x5565ac4a04c0] stream 0 : no TS found at start of file, duration not set
[mpeg @ 0x5565ac4a04c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg2video, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this post](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2decoding__encoding_8c-example.html) (search for `video_encode_example`).

Comment: @G.M. I've updated the question to show the result of my attempts.

Comment: Are you asking few questions in a sequence? Try replacing `"mpeg"` in `avformat_alloc_output_context2(&enc_inf.oc, NULL, "mpeg", filename);` to other format like `"mp4"`. `"mpeg"` format supports only old codecs, and doesn't support H.264 codec.

Comment: @Rotem Yes those questions are related, normally the code should not reach that part since it's a fail safe rather than whats actually supposed to happen, but i'll give it a go. If it really is out-dated how can I get one that supports new codecs?

Comment: Try `"mp4"` ...

Comment: @Rotem No, I've tried it but it's still the same.

Comment: Consider to updating your question with a reproducible code sample. Post something we can build and execute.

Comment: @Rotem I would love toi but my code is really long, it's a program that takes inputs using ffmpeg, then opengl draws them on a window, editing them and finally reading the window's rgb data and encodes that read data. The program normally works fine except for its low quality. The video looks normal quality in the opengl window but is really low quality. What I have provided is the smallest I can without getting into much detail.